# Elastic Beanstalk Rails not running .ebextensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to deploy my rails project to elastic beanstalk. However, the commands in the `.ebextensions` folder did not run. I am sure it did not run because I have a gem as such:

```
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
```

It requires `git` to clone the gem, and my deployment are failing at this exact point.

```
[Instance: i-000294aa0a767f205] Command failed on instance. Return code: 11 Output: (TRUNCATED)...t error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git'
"/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/ckeditor-1fd593e0d9f7d7cbd0713285fc8f7edcb38af06e"
```

I tried YAML linting and the file has no syntax error.

I checked the file location is also correct.

What is not working?

[image: Config files]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this thread on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5ykbz2/ebextensions_not_working_with_eb_cli/), I need to commit or at least stage the files